# Ocultar la verdadera ruta de una URL con Nginx

Tags: nginx

Quiero que una URL como esta:

```
https://hola.es/api/1/email/verify_email?token=asdf&username=stackoverflow
```

Se convierta en:

```
https://hola.es/email/verify_email?token=asdf&username=stackoverflow
```

¿Es posible hacer esto utilizando Nginx como proxy?

Answer (score 1):

La configuración de tu Nginx para enmascarar la url seria la siguiente, agrega las siguientes lineas:

```
# nginx configuration
location /api/email/ {
    alias /email/;
}
```